# MS Access: Determining the 2nd highest value across 4 columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

similar questions have been asked, but I think mine is slightly different because I am going across columns and not down columns. So I have these 4 columns (A to D) in an Access table. In Excel I would just use the SMALL function to determine the 2nd or 3rd highest across each row. But how can I do that in Access and/or SQL? Been quite challenged by this and is the bottleneck in our work, so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

*A B C D

*0 3    0 0

*0 9 7  7

*0 6 5 4

Comment: What should the values be when there are ties?

Comment: So if the four numbers are for example 5 7 9 7, the result would be 7. I guess ideally, one would just sort across the the columns in descending order and take the second distinct number from the top.

Answer (score 0):

This is painful.  One method is elaborate conditional logic.  MS Access does not make this simple:

```
select switch(a > b and a > c and a > d,
              switch(b > c and b > d, b,
                     c > d, c,
                     1=1, d
                    ),
              b > a and b > c and b > d,
              switch(a > c and a > d, a,
                     c > d, c,
                     1=1, d
                    ),
              c > a and c > b and c > d,
              switch(a > b and a > d, a,
                     b > d, b,
                     1=1, d
                    ),
              1=1,
              switch(a > b and a > c, a,
                     b > c, b,
                     1=1, c
                    )
             )
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for that. I was trying to do it via CASE approach rather than switch. But I feel like both ways are exhaustive.

Comment: @IDR_SQL_HELP . . . MS Access doesn't support `CASE`.

Comment: Oh! That's why it's not working for me... Oops... Thanks Gordon